# Delete duplicate chars from a string

Tags: java, string, duplicates

im asked to write a program that removes duplicate letters from a string
**note: uppercase and lowercase letters are considered duplicates.
I wrote the code and it's working for all inputs without spacebars, when an string is given with spaces, it show errors.
i have to use loops and arrays only, no extra functions or hashs,
this is my code that ALMOST works:

```java
case 2:
    System.out.println("Give the string input");
    String original=reader.next();
    char[] charts=original.toCharArray();
    int length=charts.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<length; j++){
            if(charts[i]==charts[j]||charts[i]+32==charts[j] ||charts[i]-32==charts[j]){
                int temp=j; //duplicate element index
                for (int k=temp; k<length-1; k++){ //delete shifting elements to left.
                    charts[k]=charts[k+1];
                }//inner inner for
                j--;
                length--; // reduce char array length because we removed a character
            }//if

        }//inner for

    }//for
    String CleanString= new String(charts); //new string without repeated chars
    CleanString=CleanString.substring(0,length); //set its length 
    System.out.println("New str = "+CleanString);
    break;
```

Comment: can you provide any specific input for which it is failing?

Comment: The problem is that you are using `next()` instead of `nextLine()` which only reads one token. A token is basically text until a space, so a single word. To read the full input, use `nextLine()`.

Comment: "when an string is given with spaces, it show errors." - what errors?

Comment: `if(charts[i]==charts[j]||charts[i]+32==charts[j] ||charts[i]-32==charts[j])` - this will treat some punctuation characters as "the same" as some lowercase letters. Use `Character.toLowerCase(a) == Character.toLowerCase(b) || Character.toUpperCase(a) == Character.toUpperCase(b)` instead.

Comment: You could save yourself one line: `String cleanString = new String(charts, 0, length);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use Scanner's method `nextLine()` to read string with spaces and process it with your algorithm

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String original = scanner.nextLine();
```

By the way, if you cannot use regular expressions, you maybe want to use count sort-based approach. Create an array of size equal to maximum size of char. Iterate over string and increment an array element of index `X` when you meet character value `'X'`. Add `X` to your array of chars. When you meet `array[X] >= 1`, do not add X to array.

Comment: He has definitely declared reader as a scanner in the above. Otherwise he was unable to take input.

Comment: @AbdulAlimShakir I edited my answer for clearance

Comment: i declated scanner as :
static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
i declared again like you said and the code worked, thanks my friend much appreciated <3

Comment: @WardJub yeah, I know. I just decided to make it clear for other readers :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine. Just use this code at third line:

```
String original="";
original+=reader.nextLine();
```